# Working with complex numbers in real time with GNU Radio

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, telecommunication, gnuradio

I need to work with data received from the USRP (using the gr-sounder to be specific), and I'm not exactly sure how I would do that. Are there any python packages I can use to work with the data, and more specifically, how would I use them.

To be more specific, I need to calculate the error between vectors in real time.

`e = |h1 - h2| ^ 2` where each h is an impulse response vector.

Also, a plot of the incoming data would be great.

Thanks

**Edit. Heres some more info.**

I'm working on a project to determine by how much a channel is changing by measuring the changes in the complex impulse response. I'm using GNU Radio sounder to measure the impulse response, and my plan is to take a simple moving average of the impulse response vectors over N periods, and then calculate the error between averages.

So for instance, lets say `h_avg1` is a vector which is the average of the first `N` impulse response vectors (which are periodic/repeating) `(h1 + h2 + ... + hN) / N`, and h_avg2 is a vector consisting of the average of the second N impulse response vectors. Using the above formula, I want to calculate the difference between the two averages. I dont really need to work with successive periods, so instead, I'm working with averages.

GNU Radio sounder provides a list of complex numbers, which represents the impulse response vector. What I need to do is perform VECTOR addition, VECTOR division, VECTOR subraction, and VECTOR multiplication, given this list of complex numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python and Numpy have a variety of methods for reading data depending on the format. And of course numpy is built to deal with numerical operations on array data, real and complex.

Plotting data could be accomplished using matplotlib:

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/

although there are other packages like Mayavi and Chaco as well among others that wrap general visualization software.

You'll need to specify your needs/problems in much greater detail if you want specific help.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the lack of detail. I added more to my initial question.

Comment: @BDuelz: Complex numbers, vector addition, multiplication, etc are all easily accomplished in numpy. Have you taken a look at the documentation, user's guide and examples? Is there something specific that you are having trouble with?

Comment: I was merely asking what the best package to use would be. Thank you.